# Search and paste in new worksheet with criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets. 1 with data (worksheet 1) and 1 where I need to paste it (worksheet 3). The problem is I am searching for a value like 8010 that can occur multiple times in worksheet 1, I then need to add all values that relate to 8010. Then I need the macro to find the same value (8010) in worksheet 3 and put the number found by the macro. so if 8010 is in A10 then the result needs to be visible in F10 in worksheet 3. I already know how to calculate for each value individually, however, I would like to not make one for each value since the values might change in the future.

The first example shows how it works for an individual one, the second one is what I am currently working on. Example 2 currently only shows 0s for each value in worksheet 3.

```
Sub example1()

Dim j As Long
For j = 0 To 1000000

Dim sum As Long
If Sheets(1).Range("B" & 5 + j).Value = "5000" Then
If Sheets(1).Range("J" & 5 + j).Value = "2020" Then
sum = sum + Sheets(1).Range("F" & 5 + j).Value
End If
End If

Next j
Sheets(3).Range("F" & 25).Value = sum

End Sub



Sub Example2()
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

'Run through result worksheet
For i = 6 To 300

'Run through data worksheet
For j = 5 To 10000

Dim sum As Long
'If there isn't a code then do not "get" it
If Sheets(3).Range("A" & i).Value > 1 Then
If Sheets(3).Range("A" & i).Value < 9999 Then

If Sheets(3).Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B" & j) Then
If Sheets(1).Range("J" & j).Value = Year(Now()) - 1 Then
sum = sum + Sheets(1).Range("F" & j).Value

End If
End If

'After looping through data worksheet sum to result worksheet
Sheets(3).Range("F" & i).Value = sum
'Write sum 0 for next code
sum = 0

End If
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like maybe you could more-easily use a `SUMIFS()` worksheet formula?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams,  I tried to prevent using sumifs() because there are many similar files in which I will have to use this kind of calculation. Thank you for trying to help me out. I discovered the fault in my code being the sum = 0 should be outside of the j loop as well as the fact that my code searches for a value and the information was formatted as a text.